# How to get ON CONFLICT IGNORE working in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, upsert

I'm trying to ignore inserts if a tag and url combo exist already:

```
INSERT INTO tags(tag, url) VALUES (?, ?); 
              ON CONFLICT(url, tag) IGNORE
```

I have a UNIQUE INDEX on `(tag, url)`

```
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tag_url ON tags (tag, url)
```

The app just crashes saying `[uncaught application error]: SqliteError - UNIQUE constraint failed: tags.tag, tags.url`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are using SQLite's [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) syntax incorrectly.

First, you have a `;` right after the `INSERT` statement and before `ON CONFLICT`, which separates the statements as different statements.
This means that the `INSERT` statement is executed as a simple statement (without the `ON CONFLICT` clause making any difference), so you get the `UNIQUE constraint failed` error.

Also, you are using the keyword `IGNORE` instead of `DO NOTHING`.

Change your code to:

```
INSERT INTO tags(tag, url) VALUES (?, ?)
ON CONFLICT(tag, url) DO NOTHING;
```

You could achieve the same with the `INSERT OR IGNORE` syntax:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tags(tag, url) VALUES (?, ?);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5a70c4bef72f7ff833098156257a983d).

Comment: Very good solution, I used it to make a "bulk" action of passing messages to "already seen" in my app : INSERT OR IGNORE INTO old_messages SELECT id FROM new_messages"